# Is it possible to define a default persistence-context-ref for an EJB jar?

Tags: jakarta-ee, persistence, ejb, ear

I have an EAR project in which I defined

- a "persistance" JAR containing only the entities I want to persist (and a persistence.xml)
- an EJB Jar containing the active components

When deploying those components in an EAR (built using maven plugins), I always get

> `org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Could not resolve a persistence unit corresponding to the persistence-context-ref-name [base-entities] in the scope of the module called [ear-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT#ejbs-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar]. Please verify your application.`

How can I fix that ? I first thought about defining a `persistence-context-ref` for the whole EJB jar (in ejb-jar.xml), but it doesn't seem to be possible. So, should i write a secondary `persistence.xml` linking to the first ?

Comment: Does the persistence-context-ref have a persistence-unit-name?  In what way would defining a persistence-context-ref for the whole EJB jar help (e.g., using java:module in an EE6 application server)?

Comment: @bkail Can you explain your point further ? I'm not that confident regarding those aspects.

Comment: persistence.xml contains <persistence-unit name="pu"/>.  The corresponding <persistence-context-ref/> should have a <persistence-unit-name>pu</persistence-unit-name>.  javaee_6.xsd says, "an optional persistence unit name.  If not specified, the default persistence unit is assumed."  I'm not a JPA expert, so I don't know how to specify the "default persistence unit".

Answer (score 0):

As dumb as it seems (afterwards) the simplest solution to that problem is to put in the EJB jar a persistence.xml that copies the initial one. Indeed, from what I understand, the EAR will load persistence elements from the EJB module (and not from the JAR). As a consequence, it is the EJB module that must define the persistence.xml configuration file.